# C# don't serialize inherited class

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, serialization

I have a class that keeps certain data (for a game editor), for its use in my program it must inherit the class `System.Windows.Controls.Image`.

The class looks like this:

```
public class GameObjectInstance : Image
{
    public string InstanceName { get; set; }
    public string ObjectX { get; set; }
    public string ObjectY { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

`Image` must be inherited because I must draw the `GameObjectInstance` on a Canvas to display the image but I must also retain the specific `GameObjectInstance` data.

My program must save a number of these `GameObjectInstance` classes to files somewhere.
I am trying to do this via serialization, and I have discovered that the `XmlSerializer` doesn't support this. I have also tried serializing using the `BinaryFormatter` but that does not work either.

How can I serialize so that I ignore the inherited properties (I don't need their data saved)?

Comment: Is it a data model used by the editor, or is it a ui model used by the ui? If it's both, it's probably time for a rethink along model-view separation lines.

Comment: It's used as both, but I don't know how I would separate them. As I need to show all of this data in the UI, but I still data there to store. Although my editor has worked nearly perfectly until now with how I've set everything out.

Comment: Maybe I could `GameObjectInstanceView` which inherits `Image` and has a property for the `GameObjectInstance`?

Comment: Usually, you'd create a model that is not concerned with presentation. Then you'd build a UI that takes a model and renders the model to the screen. The model doesn't know anything about the UI.

Comment: I have done that. The only exception is that `GameObjectInstance` class.

Comment: Okay, I will pursue that in my development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't inherit from image but rather define a property of type Image in your class. Use [XmlIgnore] to mark the properties that you do not want to serialize.